# Displaying results of a variable not common with another variable in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I have an OWL file, which stores the triples Person-hasFriend-Person relations. The OWL file has information about 10 Persons and the only information it has is about `hasFriend`.

All persons have `hasFriend` relation with `A` and only five persons have `hasFriend` relation with `B`. Now, I want to query those five persons who have `hasFriend` relation only with `A` by a query which will display names of persons who do not have `hasFriend` relation with `B`. How can I implement this in SPARQL?

Here I am asking for an indirect way of displaying the names of persons who have `hasFriend` relation with `A`.

Comment: Not tested: `SELECT ?a WHERE { ?a :hasFriend :A . FILTER NOT EXISTS {?a :hasFriend :B . } }`

Comment: Thank you Stanislav Kralin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yous should provide some details of your OWL file. However, if I understand well what you want, your query would look similar to this:

```
select ?person where {
  ?person hasFriend A.
  FILTER (NOT EXISTS {?person hasFriend B})
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.